# Serialization/Deserialization and non-default constructors

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, attributes, initialization

Consider this class:

```
[Persistable]
public sealed class FileMoveTask : TaskBase
{
     [PersistMember]
     public string SourceFilePath { get; private set;}

     [PersistMember]
     public string DestFilePath { get; private set;}

     public FileMoveTask(string srcpath, string dstpath)
     {
         this.SourceFilePath = srcpath;
         this.DestFilePath = dstpath;

         //possibly other IMPORTANT initializations
     }

     //code
}
```

I can persist the objects of this class, by serializing all the members with attribute `PersistMember`. But I'm facing some problems (design problems) during the deserialization  process. In particular, the problem is with the *"possibly other IMPORTANT initializations"* which might be there in the constructor, and the programmer may decide **not** to make few members persistable (i.e not adding `PersistMember` to them) possibly because that doesn't make sense.

In such situation, how would I deserialize the object to the exact same state as it was? I suppose, this question boils down to this: how would I call the non-default constructor, passing the *same* arguments to it, which was passed before? Is there any way to do that? Can we make some rules which can be enforced by the compiler (sort of metaprogramming)? Constructor attributes can help here?

Comment: What type of serialization are you using? XML, ...?

Comment: @RuiJarimba: I'm using custom serialization, written by myself. That serializes the object to XML object of type `XElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that in two ways. Use convention over configuration (name the constructor parameters as the properties and do not include a default constructor):

```
[Persistable]
public sealed class FileMoveTask : TaskBase
{
     [PersistMember]
     public string SourceFilePath { get; private set;}

     [PersistMember]
     public string DestFilePath { get; private set;}

     public FileMoveTask(string sourceFilePath, string destFilePath)
     {
         this.SourceFilePath = srcpath;
         this.DestFilePath = dstpath;

         //possibly other IMPORTANT initializations
     }

     //code
}
```

Explicitly tag the constructor arguments with your attribute and search for the constructor which have been tagged:

```
[Persistable]
public sealed class FileMoveTask : TaskBase
{
     [PersistMember]
     public string SourceFilePath { get; private set;}

     [PersistMember]
     public string DestFilePath { get; private set;}

     public FileMoveTask([PersistMember("SourceFilePath")]string srcpath, [PersistMember("DestFilePath")]string dstpath)
     {
         this.SourceFilePath = srcpath;
         this.DestFilePath = dstpath;

         //possibly other IMPORTANT initializations
     }

     //code
}
```

the attribute or the argument name isn't used to know which property to set, but to know which information from the serialize data to use when invoking the constructor.

Comment: That seems to be good enough. I will try this. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use existing well known techniques.
For example, take a look at other serialization mechanisms that are used in .NET framework (and you'll noticed what the huge diversity is).

For example, in [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [SoapFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) uses following technique for deserializing objects:

1. Obtaining "raw" object by calling [FormatterServices.GetUnitializedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx)
2. Call separate pre-serialization method on constructed object (by checking methods marked with [OnSerializingAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute.aspx)).
3. Deserialize object's state (by checking appropriate attributes to understand what fields serializer should skip and what fields it should deserialize).
4. Call post-serialization method on deserialized object (by checking methods marked with [OnSerializedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializedattribute.aspx)).

On the other [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) uses absolutely different algorithm: it requires parameterless constructor that should be used as "pre-serialization" and "post-serialization" steps.

So my point is that it solely depends on serializer's type and its implementation. And in still requires some mental efforts from both serializer's author and serializer's consumer.

So I strongly suggested to use one of the existing techniques but not invent the wheel (like add some other custom attributes to restore object's state). You can even use existing attributes to simplify migration from .NET-serializing facilities to custom serialization mechanisms (as well as using additional attributes like [NonSerializableAttrubite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx)).

Comment: Agreed, no need to reinvent the wheel